# laravel7 : Fetch data from sessions table using a key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to store sessions in database and fetch data from sessions table. For that i did

- I have changed SESSION_DRIVER=database in .env file.

---

- My code is as below to set session data

---

```
$userdata=Login::check_valid_token($token);
if(isset($userdata->username) && $userdata->username<>'')
 {
  Session::flush();
  session()->put('userdata',(array)$userdata);
 }
```

- An entry has been created in sessions table as
  [image]

- I have tried to fetch session data as below

---

```
$session_data=session()->get('userdata');
echo "<pre>";print_r($session_data);exit;
```

---

Its outputting as empty array, I need the session data fetched from database. Can someone suggest this.

Note : I am using my laravel application in incognito mode as iframe below

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/laravel-main-web-app/public/logincheck/edlaqed" frameBorder="0" height="676px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: what is `$token`?

Comment: Hi lagbox : url will be something like this http://localhost/laravel-main-web-app/public/logincheck/edlaqed. edlaqed is used to find in the database and get the record and its happening, but session is getting lost thats the issue

Comment: Reason why i am going with session database is because third party cookies are blocked

Comment: the session system is expecting a cookie to load the session ... how would it know to use something random from the URL?

Comment: my session data is in sessions table and in payload column. But session()->get('userdata'); is giving null data in incognito mode. I want these sessions to work with database and not with cookie. Reason is third party cookies are blocked from chrome browser and i cannot tell users to enable it.

Comment: that is where the session data is stored ... the session system still needs a way to get the session id to look that data up and it uses cookies to do that, so how is it supposed to know to use some random data in the URL to do that look up instead of using a cookie to get the session id?

Comment: thanks for making me understand. Is there any plugin or any way to enable third party cookies which are blocked for site ? eg : I have tried : https://www.cssscript.com/javascript-library-for-blocking-third-party-cookies-installed-by-js-cookies-enabler-js/ but it did not work for me